# React js event handler in Smart Components with arrow functions and Default params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, arrow-functions

As you might know we can create *arrow functions* as event handlers without binding *this* (with Babel Stage 2 support). In React with Redux we have Smart and Dumb Components. Hence I would like to create state modifying event handlers in the Smart Components with ***default params*** (for reusability) and pass them on to Dumb Components as props as detailed below : -

```
// SmartComponent.js

class SmartComponent extends Component {

  state = {count: 0};

  handleClick = (inc = 1) => this.setState({count: this.state.count + inc});

  render = () => <DumbComponent handleClick={this.handleClick} />
}

// DumbComponent.js

function DumbComponent(props) {
 return <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Submit</button>;
}
```

The problem is I get a console log stating that the passed arrow function is an object and not a function. It would work as expected if we create an arrow function as below, or if the initial arrow function doesn't have a ***default param*** in the DumbComponent.

```
// DumbComponent.js

function DumbComponent(props) {
 return <button onClick={() => this.props.handleClick()}>Submit</button>;
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions to make it work without a second arrow function would be much appreciated.

Comment: Given code works for me. What's the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: Where do you initialize this.state.count?